# Issue with ACF on Wordpress when Creating User

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

Got an issue with my code, See Below

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record',  'thewpchannel_elementor_form_create_new_user' , 10, 2 );
function thewpchannel_elementor_form_create_new_user($record,$ajax_handler)
{
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings('form_name');
    //Check that the form is the "create new user form" if not - stop and return;
    if ('Create New User' !== $form_name) {
        return;
    }
    $form_data = $record->get_formatted_data();
    
    $username=$form_data['Username']; //Get the value of the input with the label "User Name"
    $password = $form_data['Password']; //Get the value of the input with the label "Password"
    $email=$form_data['Email'];  //Get the value of the input with the label "Email"
    $user = wp_create_user($username,$password,$email); // Create a new user, on success return the user_id no failure return an error object
    $user_role = new WP_User($user);
    $user_role->set_role('unimproved_user');
    
    if (is_wp_error($user)){ // if there was an error creating a new user
        $ajax_handler->add_error_message("Failed to create new user: ".$user->get_error_message()); //add the message
        $ajax_handler->is_success = false;
        return;
    }
    $last_name=$form_data["Last Name"]; //Get the value of the input with the label "Last Name"
    $company_name=$form_data['acf']['Company Name']; // Get Company Data from form
    update_field( 'field_6182b31388dbe', $company_name, 'user_'.$user );
    wp_update_user(array("ID"=>$user,"first_name"=>$company_name,"last_name"=>$last_name)); // Update the user with the first name and last name
}
```

Now the `$company_name` field isn't working for me, I'm unable to capture anything from the form. The form is built with basic Elementor and ACF. I've tried the method you see, I've tried doing `$form_data['field_6182b31388dbe']` and a few more variations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Sam

Comment: What happens if you var_dump or similar log function of $_POST? Also interested in seeing a log of what comes in $form_data. These are needed in order to help you further

Comment: are you still interested in this, or did you find a solution?